# Deploy minimized Openlayers manually

Tags: deployment, build, openlayers-6

There was previously a documentation to build a minimized.js embedding the necessary modules for a particular project with a configuration file.
The french version can still be found, although outdated at :
https://openlayers.org/workshop/fr/custom-builds/create.html

For those like me preferring to avoid developing within node, that was handy!

What would be the way to do so with Openlayers 6?

____ EDIT _____
I tried to be nore specific in the new version of this question at: [Minified OpenLayers in CommonJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69602506/minified-openlayers-in-commonjs)

Comment: We'd like to see your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is on openlayers.org. It is specified in the quickstart part.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/quickstart.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you, that's the way I use to develop with Openlayers. But between this way of using Openlayers and have your users download the full ol.js, and the other path described in 'build an application' that describes how to develop within node, there is no middle ground how-to build a minified version of the library with just the necessary modules for your map.